# what is the angle here in this cyclic triangle?

Tags: geometry, trigonometry

[image: nn]

If I join the chord then I am getting the angles of the triangle are $45,45,90$ so $\theta=180-2x$ where $x$ is the angle of the other triangle whose angle is $\theta$

Comment: Hint: Inscribed Angle Theorem. (It may help to draw the full circle.)

Comment: The central angle is twice the inscribed angle.  http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inscribed_angle#Theorem

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you draw a line from the center of the circle to your angle, you get 2 isoscele triangles, so your angle is the sum of those 2 other angles in this quadrangle. the sum of all angles of quadrangle is $$360^{\circ}$$ so your angle is $$\frac{360^{\circ}-90^{\circ}}{2} = 135^{\circ}$$

**Explanation:**

[image]
$$AD = AB = AC$$
$$\angle{ADB} = \angle{ABD} ; \angle{ADC} = \angle{ACD}$$
$$\angle{BDC} = \angle{ADB} + \angle{ADC} = \angle{ABD} + \angle{ACD}$$
$$\angle{BAC} + \angle{ABD} + \angle{BDC} + \angle{ACD} = 360^{\circ}$$
$$90^{\circ} + 2\angle{BDC} = 360^{\circ}$$
$$\angle{BDC} = \frac{360^{\circ}-90^{\circ}}{2} = 135^{\circ}$$

Answer (score 2):

Draw the rest of circle (complete the circle),

```
Inscribed Angle =(1/2)Intercepted Arc
```

[image]
$$m(\widehat{CDB})=\frac{1}{2}m( \stackrel \frown{CEB})$$
$$m(\widehat{CDB})=\frac{1}{2}270^{o}=135^{o}$$